# How can I achieve this high-detail smoke turbulence in mantaflow (2.83)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I was wondering how I could achieve something similar to this effect using the mantaflow smoke simulator in blender 2.83: [image: example frame]

The Original Video is [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cinema4D/comments/gs40oi/turbulence_fd_and_octane/). I have been trying using turbulence force fields and different scaling, size, strength, and flow values but the smoke always comes out in two big blobs, instead of clumping the way a particle simulation would with the same force fields. I also am having trouble shading my smoke the same way using the principled volume node (volume scatter and absorption do not work for me) I would appreciate any help or insight you may have. Thank you!

EDIT: Here is a picture of what happens when I try and use a smoke sim and turbulence field: [image: example result]